# What is the React way of inserting an icon into another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an WithIcon wrapper component which would insert a child (icon) into a wrapped component.

Let's say I have a button:

```
<Button>Add item</Button>
```

I want to create a component WithIcon which will be used like this:

```
<WithIcon i="plus"><Button>Add item</Button></WithIcon>
```

Ultimately what I want to achieve is this:

```
<Button className="with-icon"><i className="me-2 bi bi-{icon}"></i>Add item</Button>
```

Notice the added className and the  tag within the Button's body.

I'm trying to figure out how the WithIcon component's code should look like. What is the React way of achieving this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardest part was the rules of using the `WithIcon` Will we only have one ?
Will we have only it at the leftmost ? Something like that.

But if we follow your example. We can relatively write something like this for the WithIcon

```
const WithIcon = ({ i, children }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return (
      <>
        <i className={`me-2 bi bi-${i}`}></i>
        {React.cloneElement(child, { className: "with-icon" })}
      </>
    );
  });
};
```

Then we can just use it the way you want it

```
<WithIcon i="plus"><Button>Add item</Button></WithIcon>
```

What we do is just looping through the children which in react is any nested jsx you throw in it (Button in our case)

You can find my fiddle here : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-font-awesome-forked-321tz?file=/src/index.js

**UPDATE**
So my previous answer does not fully meet the end result we want. The  will need to be the main parent

The idea is still quite the same as before but here we are infering the type of the component we passed inside the `WithIcon` This also adds a safeguard when we passed a nested component inside the WithIcon

```
const WithIcon = ({ i, children }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    const MyType = child.type; // So we can get the Button
    return (
      <MyType className="with-icon">
        <i className={`me-2 bi bi-${i}`}></i>
        {(React.cloneElement(child, {}), [child.props.children])}
      </MyType>
    );
  });
};
```

I think I'll go to sleep I'll update the rest of the explanation at later date.
See the fiddle here :
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-font-awesome-forked-y43fx?file=/src/components/WithIcon.js

Note that this code does not preserved the other props of the passed component, but you can relatively add that by adding {...child.props} at the `MyComponent` which is just (reflection like?) of infering the component.

Of course also have another option like HOC Enhancers to do this but that adds a bit of complexity to your how to declare your component api. So Pick whats best for ya buddy

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this just adds the <i> tag before the Button. I want the <i> tag to be inserted into the Button, and also add a class name "with-icon" to the Button.

Comment: ahh right the adding of class to the button body. yep will update the answer pretty much soon. :)

Comment: ohh sorry i am answering this at half awake mode. I noticed that the end result you want is <Button> will be the root parent

Comment: @janhink I updated the answer, sorry mate

Comment: Thank you for the update, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm not sure there's any point in keeping your original answer around, for the sake of simplicity, why don't you edit your answer to keep only the correct one? You can also simplifiy `(React.cloneElement(child, {}), [child.props.children])` to just `child.props.children`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a higher order component?

```
const withIcon = (icon, Component) => ({children, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <Component className="with-icon" {...props}>
            <i className=`me-2 bi bi-${icon}` /> 
            {children}
        </Component>
    );
}
```

Then the usage is

```
const ButtonWithIcon = withIcon("your-icon", Button);

<ButtonWithIcon>Add Item</ButtonWithIcon>
```

From my experience with react it usually comes down to either using a property inside the component like here (https://material-ui.com/api/button/) or higher order component like what I described.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely a way to do it, but I was specifically asking for a <WithIcon> component which encapsulates any other component. Therefore I'm going to mark @keysl's answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common patterns used in React for achieving this kind of composition:

#### [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Start by defining a component for your button:

```
const Button = ({ className, children }) => (
  <button className={className}>{children}</button>
);
```

Then the higher-order component can be implemented like this:

```
const withIcon = (Component) => ({ i, className = '', children, ...props }) => (
  <Component {...props} className={`${className} with-icon`}>
    <i className={`me-2 bi bi-${i}`} />
    {children}
  </Component>
);
```

Usage:

```
const ButtonWithIcon = withIcon(Button);

<ButtonWithIcon i="plus">Add Item</ButtonWithIcon>
```

#### [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Start by defining the context provider for the icon:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const Icon = createContext('');

const IconProvider = ({ i, children }) => (
  <Icon.Provider value={i}>{children}</Icon.Provider>
);
```

and then your component:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';

const Button = ({ className = '', children }) => {
  const i = useContext(Icon);

  if (i) {
    className += ' with-icon';
    children = (
      <>
        <i className={`me-2 bi bi-${i}`} />
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button className={className}>{children}</button>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<IconProvider i="plus"><Button>Add Item</Button></IconProvider>
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrick, both these approaches also work! However, I was specifically asking for a <WithIcon> component which encapsulates any other component. Therefore I'm going to mark @keysl's answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @janhink that's fine. You asked for the "react way". And I took that to mean using existing, composable patterns that fulfill the functional requirement of what you needed, rather than the exact literal syntax you requested. By the way, in their answer, `{(React.cloneElement(child, {}), [child.props.children])}` can be simplified to `{child.props.children}`.